# Read on/off signal from high speed 5v single wire bus

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I am trying to read from a single wire 5v bus that should be either ~0v or ~5v and change at most every 25 microseconds.

On the hardware side: I am just connecting the single wire to a pin on my arduino (atmel328p). I have tried pins 3, 8 and A0. I will need to do port manipulation to achieve the speed I need. Since the atmel328p runs 16 million operations/second this should be well within the capabilities of an arduino.

Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(;;) {
    uint8_t a = PIND;//analogRead(A0);
    if (a==0)
      // normally I won't be writing to USB serial this often, I'm
      // just simplifying as much as possible and I just want to know if this
      // actually works
      Serial.println(a);
  }
}
void loop() {}
```

What am I doing wrong on the hardware or software side?

Several other projects, such as SoftwareSerial, NewSoftSerial or AltSerial or I2C or OneWire all do the same thing, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Would a capacitor or resistor or a pull down resistor to ground help?

Comment: The notion that you could successfully read data from a single line bus like that is just a fallacy.  You don't know where the data starts and ends.  Data has to be *framed*, like a UART does, works for asynchronous transfers where you can't guarantee a constant flow of data.  Or it needs a separate line that carries the clock, like SPI does, a synchronous transfer method.

Comment: The bus I'm reading from has a framing protocol, but to having a working implementation of it, I first need to be able to detect high/low on the bus (and the amount of time its high or low)... that's what I'm focusing on first (I just want to read from the wire).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is stateless. In other words; if A0==1 then nothing happens. But if A0==0 then it jam's the Serial.print filling it faster than it can actually send out forever in a tight loop. Blowing up. You need to put some edge conditions in, to send only on the state of a transition.

You could also think about using the [PinChangeInt](http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/PinChangeIntExample) feature and supporting library to use interrupts to look for the edges. Library can be found at [here](http://code.google.com/p/arduino-pinchangeint/)

```
#include <PinChangeInt.h>

void pinfunc() {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Pin =");
  Serial.print(A0, DEC); 
  Serial.println("!");
}

void setup() {
  PCintPort::attachInterrupt(A0, &pinfunc, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

uint8_t i;
void loop() {
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(1000); // important to slow up preceding print.
  // do other things. 
  // possibly look for a flag set in pinfunc()
}
```

There are more in-depth examples in the library

Comment: I just tried attaching an interrupt for CHANGE but that doesn't work (nor does LOW or RISING or FALLING).

Specifically, I can't detect when the line is LOW. If I disconnect the line from my arduino, then its I get interrupts, but when its connected I do not.

I have connected an oscilloscope to the line so I know it is changing (moving from HIGH to LOW and LOW to HIGH). HIGH being ~4.6v and low being ~0v to ~1v.


Is there some additional hardware I need? (how does OneWire work?)...

Comment: For a pushbutton, I need to connect a 5v, ground and input line to the button (and then I just read the button line in my code). Currently, I just have the bus line connected to an arduino pin. Is this a hardware problem/solution?